# How does one determine whether a waterlogged High HP pump is electrically OK to use?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

A high power pump (the mechanic said it is a 0.75HP induction motor) is mounted on the old well using those huge bolts driven through the stone. During the recent rains the grounds were water-logged, and the well overflowed too. There is now a layer of silt a few millimeters thick at the base of the pump. There are also signs the water may have even reached the axle of the pump.

[image: 0.75HP induction motor]

There has been little sunshine during the week since the device was waterlogged. I'm sure there was some ingress of water during this incident. Understandably I'm loath to apply power to the device, as this may potentially burn the coil, blow the kit-kat et cetera.

I've applied an analog multi-meter to the supply terminals - it shows 0 resistance. The multimeter needle does not budge when the probe is connected between the supply terminals and the body. This is pretty rudimentary testing though ...

How do I determine whether the pump is safe to use? It would also be good to be able to determine whether the water within has evaporated.

p.s. *The linked image is merely a rough simulacrum of what is mounted - not an exact replica.*

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the motor did not run while wet, then the windings are probably fine because they are encased in enamel. But if it's still wet inside, or dirty, or you have a seized bearing, then trying to run it could burn out the windings. At that point you're looking at replacing the stator or the whole motor.

So the question of whether to run it or not should be based on how much it would cost to replace vs. service. If replacing the motor/pump is less than having the motor serviced, then power it up.

Comment: It did not run whilst wet; all that waterlogging had me terrified of blowing the Kit-Kat ... and then having to wade through knee deep water to replace it. Prudence, they say, is the better part of valour (+: