# What are the different ways to dry the winding of a water-logged pump?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

A follow-up to [How does one determine whether a waterlogged High HP pump is electrically OK to use?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30343/how-does-one-determine-whether-a-waterlogged-high-hp-pump-is-electrically-ok-to)

Several sites on the internet indicate it may be possible to dry the windings on a waterlogged pump using electricity. This is done by a low DC voltage to the pump, and allowing the windings to heat to the extent the water evaporates. Another method recommended is to apply low voltage AC to run the pump.

How would you go about drying the windings?

p.s. Please apply community tag to the question ; there may be more than one right answer ... and I'm hoping they will all be useful.

Comment: Leave the pump in a bowl of rice for a couple days.

Comment: @Tester101: The pump being mounted on top of the well, would it serve the purpose if one were to dump the rice on top of the pump? Also, any particular kind of rice? Brown, polished, crushed? How long should the pump be immersed in the bowl?

Comment: @Tester101: Ignore that last question please; my eyes just caught up with my mind

Answer (score 1):

You face two challenges here: silt and moisture.  Silt could gum up brushings (if present) or bearings.

Assuming the pump is full of clean water the usual drying techniques apply:

1. Disassemble to the greatest degree reasonable.
2. Rinse with clean water (no need to be shy for a pump).
3. Use compressed air to blow water out.  A bike pump works in a pinch.
4. Use a heat gun/hair dryer to accelerate drying.
5. Place the pump in a desiccant (e.g. bowl of rice works great).
6. Ensure the pump is very dry before attempting to energize.